# Making SSH connection to an individual worker node in HDinsight cluster

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

Is it possible in an HDInsight Hadoop Linux cluster to remotely connect to any of the worker nodes?

The Azure Portal provides only one server name for the purpose of connecting using SSH. I believe it is one of the head nodes , but we generally have two head nodes then which of the two head nodes gets connected?

Is not there any way to connect to an individual worker nodes this way? I don't want to just see the status in Ambari. I want to be able to directly run commands on the worker nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to do it from within the head node. So ssh into the head node the portal and then from ssh into the worker of your choose.

Answer (score 1):

As per the azure documentation, The worker nodes are not directly accessible from outside the Azure datacenter, but they can be accessed from the cluster head node via SSH.
To ssh worker nodes follow this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-linux-use-ssh-unix/).

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways:

- SSH to the head node, then from there to the worker nodes.
- Create an Azure Virtual Network -> Install HDInsight into the virtual network -> connect client machines to the virtual network (VPN for example.) Anything inside the virtual network can directly access the worker nodes.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-extend-hadoop-virtual-network/ talks more about using a virtual network with HDinsight.